# How to add padding around a carousel

Tags: html, css

So I added a carousel to my home page and it takes up the entire page and doesn't look good. I want to add some padding on all four sides, and I tried by using `<div padding:25px> </div>`  but it doesn't work.

```
<div padding:25px>
    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs- 
    slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs- 
    slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot the style attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to the top :

```
<div style='padding:25px'>
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how inline styles work.

You need to put the styles inside the `style` attribute like so:

```html
<div style="padding: 25px;"></div>
```

By the way, inline styles are not recommended. You might want to put the styles in an external stylesheet and link that stylesheet with your HTML file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code into a grid column and you're good to go.

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 offset-md-1">
    <div
        id="carouselExampleFade"
        class="carousel slide carousel-fade"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
    >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <button
            class="carousel-control-prev"
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade"
            data-bs-
            slide="prev"
        >
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
            class="carousel-control-next"
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade"
            data-bs-
            slide="next"
        >
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```